# How to insert multiple data in array to database via controller in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

i have costum table name test_category in my database that contain column :

`entity_id` (primary key and auto increment), `category_id`, and `category_name`

and i have the categories data stored in array, and i wanna insert it to database via controller in magento, is there any way to insert data in array like this

```
Array
(
    [category_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13361
            [1] => 13697
            [2] => 13755
            [3] => 13760
        )
    [category_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Baby & Toddler
            [1] => Baby & Toddler - Baby Gear
            [2] => Baby & Toddler - Baby Gear - Backpacks & Carriers 
            [3] => Baby & Toddler - Baby Gear - Backpacks & Carriers  - Accessories
        )
)
```

Comment: is there any parent child concept or are they all on same level?

Comment: @SumanSingh yes they are on the same level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

// Your data array
$catarr = array ( 
        'category_id' => array (13361,13697,13755,13760),
        'category_name' => array('Baby & Toddler','Baby & Toddler - Baby Gear','Baby & Toddler - Baby Gear - Backpacks & Carriers','Baby & Toddler - Baby Gear - Backpacks & Carriers  - Accessories')
       );

$combineArr = array_combine($catarr['category_id'],$catarr['category_name']);   
echo '<pre>';
print_r($catarr);   
print_r($combineArr);   
echo '</pre>';

// set your parent category
$parentId = '2';

foreach($combineArr as $combineArrKey => $combineArrVal) {
    try{
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setName($combineArrVal);
        //$category->setId($combineArrKey);
        //$category->setUrlKey('your-cat-url-key');
        $category->setIsActive(1);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active anchor
        $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
        $category->save();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo '<br />';
    }
}

?>
```

You can put this file on root folder and run. If you want to use it in your controller than just remove top 2 code lines.

If you want to same category Id than use

```
$category->setId($combineArrKey);
```

Comment: sorry its not the same category as magento default category

Comment: Magento default parent category is 2, you can change as per your requirement

Comment: i mean , its not related to magento category at all , i have my own model for this category table e.x : `Mage::getModel('test/category');`

Comment: Than just change model name and fields as per your table name.